Reading a file using a variable to store file name
I want the user to be able to input a file name and display the information within the file. I've used the ifstream to read the variable but it only returns an error. I implemented the error so that I could know when the program has found the file or not. I don't know if the variable needs to be wihtin the folder of the program. Tbh i dont know how to modify it for it to work.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string f_user;
string l_user;

int main(){
   cout<< "What is your first name?";
   cin >> f_user;
   cout<< "What is your last name?";
   cin >> l_user;

   string file_name= f_user + l_user + ".txt";


   ifstream inFile(file_name);

   if(inFile.is_open()){
       string c;
       while (getline(inFile, c)){
           cout<< c;
       }
   }

   if(inFile.fail()){
       cout << "User not Found"<< endl;
   }

   inFile.close();
}


The problem with the code presented here is that you haven't declared the variables f_user and l_user. You need something like string f_user, l_user; at the start of main.

Where is f_user declared?  The code shown won't compile.  Similarly for l_user.

@seraphim Edit the question, don't put the code in a comment.

Please use the [edit] facility to update your post rather than adding new information in the comments.

@seraphim So the real problem is that the code is not finding files that you think it should?

you need to specify the complete path of the file in the ifstream constructor call. Just FYI, you are trying to read the file not the variable.

@subram -- that's not necessarily true. If the file is in the current directory you can open it with just its name.

Yes, I would think the problem is that it doesn't find the file. Since i put the if(inFile(fail)) statement and it returns the "User not found".

If it fails because it looks in a wrong directory and you don't know in which one, use the following idea: create a file instead of reading it. Then look on your entire hard disk and find that file.
string file_name= f_user + l_user + ".txt";
file_name = "haha"; // use a made-up unique file name
ofstream hack;
hack.open(file_name);

Run this code, find the file and delete the code.

the file may exist, but getline may fail.
in that case fail() will return true.
In order to distint this, do something that:
   if(inFile.is_open()){
       string c;
       while (getline(inFile, c)){
           cout<< c;
       }
   } else {
       cout << "User not Found"<< endl;
   }



Note that a file can fail to open for many reasons, not just because it does not exist. The standard library won't tell you why, so consider using std::filesystem::exists() or equivalent if you need to differentiate. Of course, this does introduce a TOCTOU race condition, so be careful.

thanks, turns out the location of the file was outside of the folder that holds the code.
